# How to plot an histogram for every row of a data frame (with the first column as a character value)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, histogram

I am having difficulties in plotting a series of histograms to illustrate my data.

I have a data frame with topic prevalence for a number of documents. I would like to plot a group of histograms displaying topic prevalence for each document on the y axis. Every row would be its own histogram

This is how my data looks like:

| meta1 | Topic1 | Topic2 | Topic3 | Topic4 | Topic5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doc1 | 0.296 | 1.06 | 0.0418 | 3.85 | 3.61 |
| Doc2 | 2.06 | 1.07 | 0.223 | 1.57 | 2.18 |
| Doc3 | 4.26 | 1.68 | 0.215 | 7.76 | 14.5 |
| Doc4 | 1.72 | 23.6 | 0.900 | 3.53 | 1.41 |

This is what I have tried to do (I am really bad at using ggplot)

```
    plot2%>%
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
  geom_histogram()
```

And I get this error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("gather_") : 
  no applicable method for 'gather_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I guess the problem is that the first column is a caracter vector. I would really appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `plot2` is the name of the dataframe try -

```
library(tidyverse)

plot2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -meta1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ meta1, scales = "free") +
  geom_histogram()
```

Comment: This managed to give me the histograms, just is that they are flipped around. Each histogram represents the topic instead of the documents as I wish. I guess I should change the column value but I don't know how...

Comment: Then you need `facet_wrap(~ meta1, scales = "free")`